# Azure Web App Identity user login redirects to 404 error page

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-identity

I was able to deploy an ASP .NET Core MVC web application successfully to Azure App services.

The URL is working fine. The website homepage (before login as a user) also working fine.
[image]

The Azure app services control page of the web app.
[image]

The problem arises when a user tries to log in or sign in, he is directed to **404 error page** (I have customized it).
[image]

Following is the model class (**login.cshtml.cs**) of the login.cshtml view:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using WATERrhythmWeb.Models;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace WATERrhythmWeb.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class LoginModel : PageModel 
    {
        private readonly UserManager<WaterrhythmUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<WaterrhythmUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly ILogger<LoginModel> _logger;

        public LoginModel(SignInManager<WaterrhythmUser> signInManager, 
            ILogger<LoginModel> logger,
            UserManager<WaterrhythmUser> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        [TempData]
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

        public class InputModel
        {
            [Required]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
            public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
        }

        //To check the entered data is valid email/not
        public bool IsValidEmail(string email address)
        {
            try
            {
                MailAddress m = new MailAddress(emailaddress);
                return true;
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ErrorMessage);
            }

            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

            // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
        
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //To enablelogin with userName
                var userName = Input.Email;
                if (IsValidEmail(Input.Email)) // To check weather the entered email is valid or not
                {
                    var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        userName = user.UserName;
                    }
                }

                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userName, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true); //lockoutonfailure => true
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");

                    /************************** to get users last login data **********************************/
                    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
                    if (user == null)
                    {
                        return NotFound("Unable to load user for update last login.");
                    }
                    user.LastLoginDate = DateTimeOffset.Now;
                    var lastLoginResult = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
                    if (!lastLoginResult.Succeeded)
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException($"Unexpected error occurred setting the last login date" +
                            $" ({lastLoginResult.ToString()}) for user with ID '{user.Id}'.");
                    }
                    /************************** to get users last login data **********************************/

                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
                if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
                {
                    return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
                }
                if (result.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                    return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
                }

                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return Page();
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

Following is the **program.cs** file. I have included all the connections strings and API keys in the **appsettings.json** file and they are successfully saved in the Azure app vault also.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WATERrhythmWeb.Data;
using WATERrhythmWeb.Models;

namespace WATERrhythmWeb
{
    public class Program
    {
        public async static Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
                var loggerFactory = services.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
                try
                {
                    var context = services.GetRequiredService<WATERrhythm_DBZ1Context>();
                    var userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<WaterrhythmUser>>();
                    var roleManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole<int>>>();
                    await ContextSeed.SeedRolesAsync(userManager, roleManager);
                    await ContextSeed.SeedSuperAdminAsync(userManager, roleManager);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();
                    logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred seeding the DB.");
                }
            }
            host.Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

And following is the **startup.cs** file.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System;
using System.Text;
using WATERrhythmWeb.configuration;
using WATERrhythmWeb.Data;
using WATERrhythmWeb.Data.Repository;
using WATERrhythmWeb.Data.Repository.Interfaces;
using WATERrhythmWeb.Data.Repository.Repositories;
using WATERrhythmWeb.Hubs;
using WATERrhythmWeb.Models;
using WATERrhythmWeb.Services;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Azure;
using Azure.Storage.Queues;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Core.Extensions;

namespace WATERrhythmWeb
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<WATERrhythm_DBZ1Context>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("WATERrhythmDBConnection")));

            services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter(); //to capture database realted exceptions (to return https) 

            services.AddIdentity<WaterrhythmUser, IdentityRole<int>>(options =>
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<WATERrhythm_DBZ1Context>()
                .AddDefaultUI()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
                .AddPasswordValidator<CustomPasswordValidator<WaterrhythmUser>>();  //custom password validator

            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            //services.AddScoped<SignInManager<WaterrhythmUser>, SignInManager<WaterrhythmUser>>();
            services.AddScoped<IWeatherService, WeatherService>();

            // Password settings for the user
            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;
            });

            //For user lockouts
            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(opts =>
            {
                opts.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
                opts.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
                opts.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3;
            });

            //configure JWT 
            services.Configure<JwtConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("JwtConfig"));
            // for session handling
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

            // for session handling
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });


            //email sender
            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
            services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(Configuration);

            //sets the inactivity timeout to 5 days
            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(o =>
            {
                o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(5);
                o.SlidingExpiration = true;
            });

            //changes all data protection tokens timeout period to 3 hours
            services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(o =>
                o.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(3));

            services.AddAuthentication()

                .AddJwtBearer(jwt =>
                {
                    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration["JwtConfig:Secret"]);

                    jwt.SaveToken = true;
                    jwt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                        ValidateAudience = false,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        RequireExpirationTime = false
                    };
                })

            // Configure Google Authentication
            .AddGoogle(options =>
            {
                IConfigurationSection googleAuthNSection =
                    Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Google");

                options.ClientId = googleAuthNSection["ClientId"];
                options.ClientSecret = googleAuthNSection["ClientSecret"];
            })

            // Configure Google Authentication
            .AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
            {
                facebookOptions.AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"];
                facebookOptions.AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"];
            })

            // Configure Google Authentication
            .AddTwitter(twitterOptions =>
            {
                twitterOptions.ConsumerKey = Configuration["Authentication:Twitter:ConsumerAPIKey"];
                twitterOptions.ConsumerSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Twitter:ConsumerSecret"];
                twitterOptions.RetrieveUserDetails = true;
            });

            services.AddTransient<IRepository, Repository>();
            services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

            //custom password hasher
            services.AddScoped<PasswordHasher<WaterrhythmUser>, BCryptPasswordHasher<WaterrhythmUser>>();

            //dependacy injections to Blog article
            services.AddScoped<IBlogArticleRepository, BlogArticleRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<ITimelinePostRepository, TimelinePostRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IMediaFileRepository, MediaFileRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<IChatRepository, ChatRepository>();

            //SignalR connection
            services.AddSignalR();

            //dependancy injection of map
            services.AddScoped<IFavouriteLocation, FavouriteLocation>();
            services.AddScoped<INearByLocation, NearByLocation>();
            services.AddScoped<IBookmarkedLocation, BookmarkedLocation>();
            services.AddAzureClients(builder =>
            {
                builder.AddBlobServiceClient(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:AccessKey:blob"], preferMsi: true);
                builder.AddQueueServiceClient(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:AccessKey:queue"], preferMsi: true);
            });

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error/{0}");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}");

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            //to use sessions
            app.UseSession();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();

                endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub");      //route the chathub
            });


        }
    }
    internal static class StartupExtensions
    {
        public static IAzureClientBuilder<BlobServiceClient, BlobClientOptions> AddBlobServiceClient(this AzureClientFactoryBuilder builder, string serviceUriOrConnectionString, bool preferMsi)
        {
            if (preferMsi && Uri.TryCreate(serviceUriOrConnectionString, UriKind.Absolute, out Uri serviceUri))
            {
                return builder.AddBlobServiceClient(serviceUri);
            }
            else
            {
                return builder.AddBlobServiceClient(serviceUriOrConnectionString);
            }
        }
        public static IAzureClientBuilder<QueueServiceClient, QueueClientOptions> AddQueueServiceClient(this AzureClientFactoryBuilder builder, string serviceUriOrConnectionString, bool preferMsi)
        {
            if (preferMsi && Uri.TryCreate(serviceUriOrConnectionString, UriKind.Absolute, out Uri serviceUri))
            {
                return builder.AddQueueServiceClient(serviceUri);
            }
            else
            {
                return builder.AddQueueServiceClient(serviceUriOrConnectionString);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I feel like, redirecting to the 404 error page is due to some problem in one of the above 03 classes. That's why I thought to share them with you.
This is the first time I deployed to the Azure App service. So, if you need more information to solve the problem, I am happy to add to the question.

I am grateful if you can provide me a solution to the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your login view page redirect ?

Comment: It should redirects to the homepage again ('/'). You can see I have redirected it to the home page in the line ` returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");`. This works fine in the IIS server. (Running on local server). The issue only comes in the Azure App services. (When it is deployed).